# How can I convert a 3D volumetric primitive (8,3) in a object with 12 parameters (12,1)?

Tags: python-3.x, geometry, computational-geometry

A box is composed of 8 vertices, each with 3 values (x,y,z).
How can I translate it to an object that can represent that box in a lower space?

Having the center (3,1) + lengths ( width, length, depth = (3,1) ) and other 2 vectors ( vector 1, and vector 2) for a total of (12,1) parameters versus the original (8x4 = 24)?

Comment: Emm... You need to describe projection of the box into 2d with 12 parameters?

Comment: When you say “box”, are you referring to a rectangular cuboid, a general cuboid, or something else? Have you considered omitting any vertices that are implied by the others?

Comment: 8x4 = 24, sure ?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a parallelepiped, four non-coplanar vertices (12 coordinates) are enough, it is easy to reconstitute the missing ones by vector additions.

---

If you mean a rectangular parallelepiped, 9 reals are enough.

Let a vertex `A`, joined to vertices `B`, `C` and `D`. The edges `AB`, `AC`, `AD` are orthogonal in pairs.

If you give `Ax`, `Ay`, `Az`,`Bx`, `By`, `Bz`, `Cx`, `Cy`, `Dx`, you can reconstitute the missing coordinates by expressing orthogonality.

WLOG, `Ax = Ay = Az = 0`, and

```
Bx.Cx + By.Cy + Bz.Cz = 0
```

gives `Cz`,

while

```
Bx.Dx + By.Dy + Bz.Dz = 0
Cx.Dx + Cy.Dy + Cz.Dz = 0
```

give `Dy` and `Dz`.

---

If the boxes are known to be axis-aligned, two opposite corners (6 coordinates) are enough.